# Is spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop the same as spark-yarn?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I have been trying to follow a tutorial in order to install Spark on Windows :

https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/apache-spark-installation-on-windows/

[image: Spark Documentation]

because I would like to use the library **SparkContext** :

[image: My Python Code]

Nevertheless, in the internal repositories of my company, I could only find the two following jars :
[image: spark-yarn.jar]

I do not believe that this is the same as spark-bin-hadoop

In case someone has any information related to this, I'd be very grateful in case you'd let me know.

Answer (score 1):

spark-yarn is a JAR containing classes for interacting with YARN scheduler, not a distribution of Spark

Besides, you're using `setMaster("local")`, not `"yarn"`

Your error is clearly saying winutils could not be found on your system. This is not included with Spark, and you must download it separately. Additionally, you have under environment variables for where Spark is trying to find Hadoop libraries

Also, you should use SparkSession, not SparkContext for all entrypoints into Spark 2+; you can get a context from a session, if needed

Also, later Spark's have had much runtime improvements, so there's little reason to use a 3 year old version

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @OneCricketeer. So all I need is hadoop-331-winutils, right ? kontext.tech/article/825/hadoop-331-winutils . Is this a problem running Hadoop on Windows? Do I require a Windows native library ? (so that Hadoop could use Windows APIs )

Comment: Winutils needs to match your Hadoop version, yes, (so, winutils 2.7, for `spark..hadoop2.7`) and is specific to Windows to allow for unix-permission emulation on windows systems (e.g. `hdfs chmod`/`chown`). Native libraries aren't necessary, but may help code run faster. Hadoop only provides native libraries for Linux, and you must compile them manually otherwise. Alternatively, you could run Spark in WSL2 or Docker, which is already a linux environment.